# Setting Up Push Notification Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm confused about configuring permissions for Remote Notifications.  Having worked with Android,  I understand the typical application of permissions, but in [this documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/), it defines the permissions as assembly attributes.

```
[assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]

[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]

[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]

[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]

[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
```

Is this the actual way the supply the permissions?  I ask because everywhere else it uses the manifest, which is strange that it wouldn't use the manifest here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you provided, does add the permissions to the generated manifest, which you can see in `obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml`.

It is just an alternative way to add permissions to the application, which can be done either directly in the `AndroidManifest.xml` or in `AssemblyInfo.cs` with the method you provided.